# Android listview array out of bounds

Tags: java, android, listview

when I try to call my ArrayList.clear() method, I get this error.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 1

The method is called in the onPreExecute of my Async class.. How can I fix this?

```
private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        postList.clear();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> likeQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Likes");
        likeQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        List<ParseObject> likeList;
        try {
            likeList = likeQuery.find();
            try {
                query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Images");
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                query.setLimit(limit += 20);
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject num : ob) {
                    PostRow test1;
                    Like singleLike = new Like(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < likeList.size(); i++) {
                        if (likeList.get(i).get("imgId").equals(num.getObjectId())) {
                            isLiked = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            isLiked = false;
                        }
                    }
                    singleLike.setLikeStatus(isLiked);
                    ParseFile img = (ParseFile) num.get("img");
                    test1 = new PostRow(img.getUrl().toString(), (String) num.get("username"), num.getObjectId(), singleLike, num.getInt("likeCount"));
                    postList.add(test1);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        int position = listViewPosts.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = listViewPosts.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        listViewPosts.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
    }
}
```

Here's the full Exception:

```
09-11 10:38:20.738    4281-4281/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hristijan.likeout, PID: 4281
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 29, size is 1
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
            at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4110)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: have u understood what is IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yes, I know what that is, I just cant figure it out what causes this in my case..

Comment: what line is the error flagging?

Comment: There is no line specifies in the log, but when I remove postList.clear(); from the preExecute method, there is no error. I've added the full error log in my question above.

Comment: How is `postlist` defined? How do you call your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: postList = new ArrayList<PostRow>() where PostRow is a single row for my listview. I call my async like this: new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();

Comment: If I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after postList.clear() the error is gone, but my listView scrolls to the top all the time when I scroll to load more content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to pass in your `Adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it after you clear the list.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    postList.clear();
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit:**

Alternative way

```
private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<PostRow>>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //postList.clear();
        //do not clear
    }
    @Override
    protected List<PostRow> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<PostRow> tempList = new ArrayList<PostRow>()
        ...
                    //postList.add(test1);
                    //replace this with
                    tempList.add(test1);
        ...
        return tempList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<PostRow> tempList) {     
        super.onPostExecute(tempList);
        postList.clear();
        postList.addAll(tempList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        int position = listViewPosts.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = listViewPosts.getChildAt(0);
        int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        listViewPosts.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps, but the problem is that when I call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), my listview scrolls to the top. I guess this is because there is a moment where the listview is empty and there is no scroll. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are right. To prevent this, you can just leave the list here without clearing it, and only clear and update the new list all together when you get the new items.

Comment: Well, if I clear the postlist after I get the new items, i will delete the new items... In the doInBackground method I fill the postList with new items. I have to clear the postlist before that.

Comment: you should use another variable to store that first, only update `postList` in onPostExecute

Comment: You mean to create another ArrayList<PostRow>  postListForRefresh; and add the new items in this array. Than in my postExecute method to do this: postList.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<postListForRefresh.size(); i++){
                postList.add(i, postListForRefresh.get(i));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();